# centos6.2 upgrade python2.7 _hashlib and _ssl build failed and make [Modules/_ssl.o] Error 1

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, centos

I want to upgrade default python2.6.6 to python2.7 from source code, I installed:

```
yum groupinstall "Development tools"
yum install zlib-devel bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel sqlite-devel readline-devel tk-devel
```

but _hashlib and _ssl is failed to build.

my openssl is installed:

```
whereis openssl
openssl: /usr/bin/openssl /usr/lib/openssl /usr/lib64/openssl /usr/local/bin/openssl /usr/include/openssl /usr/share/man/man1/openssl.1ssl.gz
```

And I uncomment the Module/Setup about ssl config like this:

```
# Socket module helper for socket(2)
_socket socketmodule.c timemodule.c

# Socket module helper for SSL support; you must comment out the other
# socket line above, and possibly edit the SSL variable:
SSL=/usr/local/ssl
_ssl _ssl.c \
        -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
        -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

then

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python27/ --enable-shared
make
```

it has errors:

```
gcc -pthread -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes  -I. -IInclude -I./Include   -DPy_BUILD_CORE  -DUSE_SSL -I/usr/local/ssl/include -I/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl -c ./Modules/_ssl.c -o Modules/_ssl.o
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘newPySSLObject’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:307: warning: ‘TLSv1_method’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1596)
./Modules/_ssl.c:309: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv3_method’
./Modules/_ssl.c:309: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1302: note: expected ‘const struct SSL_METHOD *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
./Modules/_ssl.c:312: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘SSLv2_method’
./Modules/_ssl.c:312: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SSL_CTX_new’ makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/local/include/openssl/ssl.h:1302: note: expected ‘const struct SSL_METHOD *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘_create_tuple_for_X509_NAME’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:613: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Modules/_ssl.c:630: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘_get_peer_alt_names’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:732: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Modules/_ssl.c:736: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Modules/_ssl.c:741: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
./Modules/_ssl.c:802: warning: ‘ASN1_STRING_data’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/local/include/openssl/asn1.h:553)
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘PySSL_cipher’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:1140: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type
./Modules/_ssl.c: In function ‘PySSL_RAND_egd’:
./Modules/_ssl.c:1610: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RAND_egd’
make: *** [Modules/_ssl.o] Error 1
```

If dont use ssl, the make is not this error, it shows:

```
Python build finished, but the necessary bits to build these modules were not found:
bsddb185           dl                 imageop         
sunaudiodev                                           
To find the necessary bits, look in setup.py in detect_modules() for the module's name.


Failed to build these modules:
_hashlib           _ssl
```

I want to know how to fix this, Thanks.

Comment: I solve this by copy the failed modules from another machine which could compile successful.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting the output of the make command including stderr and stdout to a file and then going through that log. In my case I was using a different `openssl` libraries installed in my system. After deleting that library folder the `make` took the correct `openssl` libraries.